# Multiple infinite ladders of resistances

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm a bit stuck with this problem. I'll post the exact statement below:

Consider the circuit given. Calculate the voltage across the 100Ω Resistor. The
configuration of $I^{th}$ sub-circuit is given in Fig. 8(b). The value of $I_i$ is $I_i = 3 + 2^i A$.

[image]
[image]

I tried to consider each circuit separately and tried to get the resistances into a single one to get the equivalent answer for each subcircuit, but apparently this gives me a wrong answer. I have been told that the correct answer is zero.

Comment: This is a curious question if I understand it aright. Each subcircuit, I calculate, has a resistance or 3.236 ohm between A and B, and a resistance of 3.236 ohm between C and D.  But the resistances between A and C and between B and D are infinite, because the ladder of resistances is infinitely long. So the current sources (if such they be) on the left of the top diagram won't drive any current through the 100 ohm resistance. This all seems very unsatisfactory. Maybe I haven't understood.

Comment: @PhilipWood - I get a resistance of 3.236 ohms between A and B, but 1.236 ohms between C and D. As for the resistance between A and C, I think that that should be finite because the measuring current isn't forced to travel through the infinite chain of resistances on the upper branch of the sub-circuit diagram, but can also make use of the 0 resistance lower branch in order to get from A to C. In fact, from inspection it appears that there exists a current path from A to C that needs to travel through only three 2 ohm resistors, so the A C resistance has to be less than 6 ohms.

Comment: @SamuelWeir  I was being silly. I hadn't looked properly at the ladder.

Comment: If we just consider a current source connected to the A-B terminals of a single sub-circuit, it seems to me that network of resistors is basically acting like successive stages of voltage dividers. So if there is some voltage placed across terminals A-B, then after going through an infinite number of voltage dividers the output voltage at terminals C and D will be zero, regardless of what kind of voltage or current source is placed at terminals A B. So, yeah, I would say that the answer is zero. In fact, I'm puzzled why additional sub-circuits needed to be thrown into the problem.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I guess the circuits are there just to create confusion then?

Comment: @AbhishekMalpani - If I'm reading the problem correctly, it would appear so. But the way that problem is posed is puzzling. It goes through all of the trouble of defining various $I_i$, but that information is never used. Also, it defines various sub-circuits indexed by $i$, but it appears that all of the sub-circuits are the same and independent of $i$. Finally, you said that the official answer is zero, but zero is generally a lousy answer to have when drawing up a physics question because lots of people just guess "zero" if they are completely lost.